# Titanium UI issues

Tags: titanium

I am beginning to look at options for cross-platform mobile development.  In a couple of places I read that there are some problems with Titanium UI performance, here is a link to one of those (slide 12):

http://www.slideshare.net/bertouttier/crossplatform-tools-for-mobile-application-development

I then went to the Titanium site's App Showcase to download and test some apps to see if I noticed anything.  I decided to start with the Khan Academy app since I know that they are pretty tech savvy (or assume so since their founder has 3 degrees from MIT including Comp Sci) and have some money (a few million from Google and Gates).

It only took me about 1 minute to get to a video with captions listed below the video and the first few words of the narration. I went down to the scrolling captions and tested how the gestures felt and couldn't believe that it was barely functional.  Sometimes it goes in the wrong direction, sometimes it does nothing, and I cannot access the vertical scroll bar!

So the larger question I am trying to answer is potential not suitable for the Stack Overflow format...., which is: Is this one glitchy UI indicative of problems found in using Titanium in general?

More specific questions are: Why is the caption scrolling at the bottom of these videos so terrible?  Is this an issue caused by Titanium? Have other people run into similiar problems with UI widgets in Titanium?

FYI - I am using an iPad 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the fastest possible UI performance, going "fully" native  is probably the best overall option.  Titanium offers you flexibility in that you are writing a single application with smaller changes, if necessary, across multiple platforms.  It cuts your development time down significantly since you are able to share code across projects.

My understanding of the UI in Titanium is that they map to native controls on the target platform.  So the performance you are seeing are native controls.  The background logic of your application, the business rules, are controlled by JavaScript.

I downloaded (from iTunes) and played with the app and didn't see any issues with navigating their app.  I am running it on an iPhone 4 with IOS 6.  The animation flipping between between tables was responsive and the animations jumped in a predictable way.  Perhaps you have a different OS version?

The Khan Academy appears to be a perfect example of an app that should take advantage of cross-platform development like Titanium.  Though the app is relatively simple, it gets you access to what you need quickly and simply.  This app could then be deployed on all the supported Titanium platforms, likely without any modifications at all.

Comment: I know how Titanium works, which is why I am considering it. The captions below videos do not show on the iPhone and as all my questions deal with this specific defect, you obviously cannot address them.